# Catboost uses gpu memory, but gpu-util doesn't go up

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, catboost

I'm using catboost in order to solve multiclass classification.

When I fit model using catboost, gpu util doesn't go up. But my gpu memory-usage clearly goes up highly.

I found my model was fit using cpu, because colab with gpu runtime showed much shorter training time.

I have better gpu than colab.

I attach code and nvidia-smi result.

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(
    custom_metric=['TotalF1'],
    random_seed=42,
    logging_level='Silent',
    task_type='GPU'
)
```

```
get_gpu_device_count()
3
```

```
model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    cat_features=categorical_features_indices,
    eval_set=(X_validation, y_validation),
     logging_level='Verbose',  # you can uncomment this for text output
    plot=True
);

Warning: less than 75% gpu memory available for training. Free: 23583.5625 Total: 32480.5
Warning: less than 75% gpu memory available for training. Free: 5569.5625 Total: 32480.5

0:  learn: 0.9920891    test: 0.9923071 best: 0.9923071 (0) total: 2.54s    remaining: 42m 15s
1:  learn: 0.9280651    test: 0.9282007 best: 0.9282007 (1) total: 5.01s    remaining: 41m 40s
2:  learn: 0.8778390    test: 0.8781491 best: 0.8781491 (2) total: 7.45s    remaining: 41m 15s
3:  learn: 0.8469168    test: 0.8473046 best: 0.8473046 (3) total: 9.9s remaining: 41m 5s

....
```

Please ignore GPU device 1 and 2, they are being used by other user. I'm sure that when I fit my model, kernel try to use  device 0. As you can see, gpu devcie 0 shows no gpu-util. When I kill my catboost kernel, the gpu memory-usage return to zero. When I fit model, only gpu memory-usage goes up and gpu util doesn't increase.

[image]